# Photoshop - how to mirror a layer with a given shape e.g. a little cloud about a diagonal path or like?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

Photoshop

How to mirror a layer with a given shape e.g. a little cloud

about a diagonal path or like?

there is a path, that consists of a simple line, it is tilted 5 degree from vertical and I'd like use this path as mirroring axis

but the point is the mirroring with a tilted axis so if the path should be replaced with sg else, tell me

Please help me

Comment: What have you tried? Where is it failing?

Comment: Can you please show us what you are trying to do?  Take a screenshot or show an example of what you are trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: If you consider paid extensions and you’re not M2 Mac, my Layer Factory [has this functionality](https://layer-factory.readthedocs.io/en/latest/symmetry/index.html#using-paths)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mirror anything with custom axis in Photoshop. You can only mirror things by scaling them to -100% in width or height, but you can also rotate stuff. That's quite unnecessarily complex for such a simple task, but at least you can do it. So what you could do is:

- Draw a huge vector circle around your objects to 'save' the exact pivot point for rotation and put them into a group. Copy the angle of the path from the properties window:

[image]

- Transform the whole group with Ctrl + T and rotate it by the copied angle. You might want to change it to negative, if it doesn't rotate in a way that the path gets straight. It doesn't matter if its vertical or horizontal, just that its parallel to width or height of the image:

[image]

- Duplicate and transform the cloud. Place pivot point on the line and enter -100 to the height or width depending how your path is oriented:

[image]

- Rotate the group back and delete the circle:

[image]